# How to use Hyperlink property in Windows form Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to help about this issue, I have code inside asp.net page like;

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbl; i++)
    {
        HyperLink lnkBtn = new HyperLink();
        lnkBtn.CssClass = "btn";
        lnkBtn.Text = "WEB PAGE NAME";
        lnkBtn.NavigateUrl = "URL OF DESİRED PAGES";
        lnkBtn.Target = "myFrame";
        LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
        placeholder.Controls.Add(lnkBtn);
        placeholder.Controls.Add(linebreak);
    }
```

I'm adding the hyperlink as button to the webpage, datas coming from database. I want to do the same thing windows form application.

I found "linklabel" but I need to target it to the browser on the application. I used webkitbrowser to display pages.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Handle the [LinkClicked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked(v=vs.110).aspx) event in your WinForms code and perform whatever custom navigation from there.
Your handler would look something like this (assuming `browser` is some sort of browser control also on the Form and the `Tag` property of the link held the full Uri of the target)

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    browser.Navigate(e.Link.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- add in your Form **WebBrowser control**
- add new **button**
- add in your **button_click()** the logic for open a site in **WebBrowser**

Answer (score 1):

Link button is just a button styled as link. Put LinkButton component on form, open events and search for click event, double click on it. In generated method write:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");
```

Comment: The question appears to ask how to get the link to open in a browser control local to the application. This answer doesn't help with that.